# Mapbox GL - React Native install error

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl

While installing Mapbox GL — `npm install --save react-native-mapbox-gl`,
I'm getting this output:

```
 npm WARN minifyify@7.3.3 requires a peer of browserify@>= 5 but none was installed.`
 npm WARN react-native@0.26.2 requires a peer of react@15.0.2 but none was installed.`
```

What should I change to get the appropriate output?

This is the content of my `packages.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.26.2",
    "react-native-mapbox-gl": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^2.11.0"
}
```